# Counting cells in a column with EPPlus

Tags: c#, linq, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus in a C# application for reading an Excel (.xlsx) file. What I need to do is counting how many cells in the column `I` contain the value `Value`.

For this I have defined the following query:

```
var query = (from worksheet.Cells["i:i"]
             where cell.Value.ToString().Equals("Value")
             select worksheet.Cells);
```

Howwever this does not seem to work. I'm pretty sure that the `select` statement is wrong but I don't know what it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cell.Text` should work, assuming column `I` is the 9th column:

```
int count = worksheet.Cells[1, 9, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row, 9]
                     .Count(c => c.Text == "Value");
```

although it should also work with the address:

```
count = worksheet.Cells["i:i"].Count(c => c.Text == "Value");
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I've been looking for!